# Why is Haskell unable to resolve the number of arguments automatically?

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and I got confused by the following behavior:

I have a function, called dealWithIt.  It looks like this:

```
dealWithIt :: (Show a) => [a] -> String
dealWithIt = foldl f ""
  where f memo x = memo ++ (show x)
```

All good, it's working as expected, it gets a list of showables and concatenates them into a single string.

As much as I understand, it doesn't matter if I explicitly specify the argument received as long as it can be passed to the underlying chain of functions.  That means the following two definitions should be equivalent:

```
dealWithIt xs = foldl f "" xs
dealWithIt = foldl f ""
```

So far so good. Let's say I want to add now a special case scenario by pattern matching:

```
dealWithIt [] = "Empty list :("
```

This is where things get weird. If I don't explicitly specify the xs argument, I get the following error:

```
Equations for ‘dealWithIt’ have different numbers of arguments
```

I can live with it, but it's really interesting to me why is Haskell unable to detect what's going on and reports an error even when both variants take a single argument?

Comment: `dealWithIt = foldl f ""` already specifies the behavior for all possible arguments.  How would it make sense to define it again with another argument?

Comment: Adding a special case has nothing to do with handling all possible arguments.

Comment: The error message thrown out by compiler says that clear. These are different functions. Compare their signatures. If you need handle *special* arguments, you may use arguments pattern matching but keep same types. Or use guards, or if/case conditions.

Comment: But that's exactly what confuses me as both variants of my function have the same signature and accept a single argument of the same type. So where comes the error from?

Comment: This is a very reasonable question. The compiler could certainly expand the equations with fewer parameters. I believe it was simply a design choice to forbid that, so to provide a better error message when a parameter is accidentally forgotten instead of a cryptic type error. This design can be argued against, of course - it's a matter of preference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a rule.  A definition of a function by cases:

```
f p0 p1 = e0
f p2 p3 = e1
```

has to have the same number of patterns in the function arguments on the left-hand side for all equations.

It's partly to simplify the definition of the language; the Haskell standard defines that function definition in terms of a *single* `case` expression:

```
f x0 x1 = case (x0, x1) of
    (p0, p1) -> e0
    (p2, p3) -> e1
```

Now consider what would happen if you could say

```
f p0 p1 = e0
f p2 = e1 -- `e1` is a function
```

The language standard would have to handle that case specially, and define it as something like

```
f x0 x1 = case (x0, x1) of
    (p0, p1) -> e0
    (p2, _) -> e1 x1 -- Note that the argument to `e1` has to be supplied explicitly
```

That's an un-necessary complication for something that it's not normally sensible to do.

Furthermore, consider the definition of `foldr`:

```
foldr f z [] = z
foldr f z (x:xn) = f x (foldr f z xn)
```

Suppose you were typing it in and you forgot the `f` on the first equation:

```
foldr z [] = z
foldr f z (x:xn) = f x (foldr f z xn)
```

The current rule allows typos like this to be caught: the compiler can complain that you have a different number of arguments in different equations.  Otherwise you would get some confusing type error, which would probably be difficult to debug.  (Probably you would get an error because `z` in the first equation has to have the same type as `f` in the second equation, and `z` in the first equation has to have the same type as `f x (foldr f z xn)` in the second equation, so the first argument to `foldr` has to have an infinite type.  Infinite type errors are typically not fun to debug.)

Comment: Even `f x y = somethingWith x y` is syntactic sugar for `f = \x y -> somethingWith x y`, itself sugar for `f = \x -> (\y -> somethingWith x y)`, etc. It's always important to realise that, in a way, Haskell only exists of functions, applications, (saturated) constructor calls, and data deconstruction.